# What does "a minor variation" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Under the terms of the deal, Company A is allowed to pursue a minor variation of this technology of Company B.

Does "variation" mean "type"?
I cannot figure out what it means.

Comment: Briefly, "minor variation" means "minor change" or "small change".

Answer (score 3):

"Variation" does not mean "type" in this instance.

[variation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/variation)

There are several definitions but the one that applies here is *something slightly different from another of the same type.*

A **minor** variation emphasises that the difference is even more slight.

The wording of the sentence makes it difficult to understand. Substituting alternative words might make it easier:

> Under the terms of the deal, Company A is allowed to *[design|test|research|develop|investigate|offer]* a slightly different version of the technology *[owned|developed|provided]* by Company B.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Frank H. gives a good definition of *variation*, but the ambiguity of the sentence really comes from the lack of indication as to whether the *variation* is mandated or tolerated.

Does *. . .A is allowed to pursue a minor variation of this technology of Company B* mean

> A is allowed to pursue this technology, but it must be in the form of  a minor variation from that which Company B utilizes.

or does it mean

> A is allowed to pursue this technology of Company B, and even if it is in the form of a minor variation, it will be covered by this authorization.